# Sql developer script output

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working with SQL Developer on a school project. SQL Developer returns the query result but no script output. I also have a warning saying the table `curso` is disconnected from the join graph, can anyone help?

```
select departamento as "Sigla do Departamento",nome_depart as "Nome do Departamento", anolectivo as "Ano Lectivo", round((sum(num_presencas)*100)/sum(alunos_por_turno),1)||'%' as "Percentagem de presenças"
from ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_aulas_semana aulas_semana
join ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_turnos turnos
on aulas_semana.turno_id = turnos.id
join t_ext_curso_ei curso
on upper(trim(turnos.nomeuc)) = upper(trim(curso.unidade_curricular))
join (select turno_id,count(*) as alunos_por_turno 
      from ei_sad_proj_gisem.v_turno_user
      group by turno_id) total_inscritos
on turnos.id = total_inscritos.turno_id
join t_ext_departamentos departamentos
on departamentos.sigla_depart = departamento
where aulas_semana.marcou_presenca =1
and aulas_semana.aula_cancelada =0
group by departamento, anolectivo, nome_depart;
```

[image: query result here]

Comment: Script output only gets displayed  only if you have run a PL/SQL block or use Run script (F5) option

Comment: That I'm aware of, the problem is the query shows the output when I run the statement but when I run with F5 nothing appears on the script output.

Answer (score 4):

As of script output: include "SET SERVEROUTPUT ON" at the beginning of your script. For example:

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  l_dum varchar2(1);
begin
  select dummy into l_dum from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_dum);
end;
/
```

Doing so, "Script Output" window should display data.